# Row number for Unique value in column

Tags: sql, impala, row-number

I am joining three tables finally I get out three columns - with app_id, tenant_id, count_device.
I have an issue with the db here for some of the app_id, tenand_id is missing, but its of the same tenant. I want assign a Row()number or any variable for the same app id.

I tried by using ROW_NUMBER() function, but I am not getting the desired output, I might be missing something in PARTITION BY

| App_id | tenant_id | count_device | New_Row_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| appid1 | Tenant 1 | 100 | 1 |
| appid2 | Tenant 2 | 75 | 2 |
| appid3 | Tenant 3 | 75 | 3 |
| appid4 | Tenant 4 | 50 | 4 |
| appid1 |  | 50 | 1 |
| appid5 | Tenant 5 | 40 | 5 |
| appid3 |  | 30 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Use dense_rank, it will assign the same rank to rows with the same orderby value:

```
with mytable as(
select 'appid1' App_id, 'Tenant 1' tenant_id, 100 count_device union all
select 'appid2', 'Tenant 2', 75  union all
select 'appid3', 'Tenant 3', 75  union all
select 'appid4', 'Tenant 4', 50  union all
select 'appid1',  null     , 50  union all
select 'appid5', 'Tenant 5', 40  union all
select 'appid3',  null     , 30
)

select App_id, tenant_id, count_device,
       dense_rank() over(order by App_id) rn
  from mytable
```

Result:

```
app_id  tenant_id   count_device    rn
appid1  NULL        50              1
appid1  Tenant 1    100             1
appid2  Tenant 2    75              2
appid3  NULL        30              3
appid3  Tenant 3    75              3
appid4  Tenant 4    50              4
appid5  Tenant 5    40              5
```